# LINQ Join tables, group and sum items only if values in stock is 1

Tags: vb.net, linq

I would like to join 4 table, main table in this example is "MAGAZ101" (records on screen).

Table "TOWARY" keep name of items, unit of measurement(kg, quantity), itc.

Table "MAGAZ01" keep info about item in stock (1 in, 0 sold).

Table "PRZYTOW" keep info about how many same items had been take to stock also real weight of item.

Tables "MAGAZ101", "TOWARY", "MAGAZ01" are join by fields "TOWAR".

My problem is join "MAGAZ01" and "PRZYTOW" by column "DOK_PRZYJ", group and sum weight in "PRZYTOW" and also sum stock in "MAGAZ01", sum if item in table "MAGAZ01" is "1".

Here is my Code:

'''''''''

```
Dim MAGAZYNGLOWNY = (From tab1 In MAGAZ101.AsEnumerable()
                         Join tab2 In TOWARY.AsEnumerable() On tab1.Field(Of String)("TOWAR") Equals tab2.Field(Of String)("TOWAR")
                         Join tab3 In MAGAZ01.AsEnumerable() On tab1.Field(Of String)("TOWAR") Equals tab3.Field(Of String)("TOWAR")
                         Join tab4 In PRZYTOW.AsEnumerable() On tab3.Field(Of String)("DOK_PRZYJ") Equals tab4.Field(Of String)("DOK_PRZYJ")
                         Select New With {
                            .Symbol = tab1.Field(Of String)("TOWAR"),
                            .Nazwa = tab2.Field(Of String)("NAZWA"),
                            .Jm = tab2.Field(Of String)("JM"),
                            .Stan = If(IsDBNull(tab3.Item("STANMAG")), 0, tab3.Field(Of Double)("STANMAG")),
                            .WAGA = If(IsDBNull(tab4.Item("WAGA")), 0, tab4.Field(Of Double)("WAGA"))
                            }).ToList
```

Group and sum:

```
Dim MAGAZYNGLOWNYSUMA = (From A1 In MAGAZYNGLOWNY
                             Group A1 By Key = New With {.SYMBOL = A1.Symbol, .NAZWA = A1.Nazwa, .JM = A1.Jm, .STAN = A1.Stan, .Waga = A1.WAGA} Into Group
                             Select New With {
                                .Symbol = Key.SYMBOL,
                                .Nazwa = Key.NAZWA,
                                .Jm = Key.JM,
                                .Stan = Group.Sum(Function(A) A.Stan),
                                .WAGA = Group.Sum(Function(A) A.WAGA)
                                    })
```

.Symbol - ID of item,

.Nazwa - name of item,

.Jm - unit,

.STAN - how many in stock,

.WAGA - weight,

Thanks in advace Adam

Answer (score 0):

If you need, ask for detail.

Here is correct working code.

1st "MAG_GLOW" joined tables 1 and 2.

2nd "dane" joined tables 3 and 4, by "TOWAR" and also "DOK_PRZYJ" in the result the table is sorted and easy to sum.

3rd "Stock" where stock is greater than 0 (sum "STAN") and where stock is greater than 0 (sum weight "WAGA")

4th "MAGAZYNGLOWNY" joined 1st step "MAG_GLOW" and 3rd step "Stock".

```
Dim MAG_GLOW = (From tab1 In MAGAZ101.AsEnumerable()
                    Join tab2 In TOWARY.AsEnumerable() On tab1.Field(Of String)("TOWAR") Equals tab2.Field(Of String)("TOWAR")
                    Select New With {
                            .TOWAR = tab1.Field(Of String)("TOWAR"),
                            .Nazwa = tab2.Field(Of String)("NAZWA"),
                            .Jm = tab2.Field(Of String)("JM")
                               }).ToList

    Dim dane = (From TAB3 In MAGAZ01.AsEnumerable()
                Join TAB4 In PRZYTOW.AsEnumerable() On TAB3.Field(Of String)("towar") Equals TAB4.Field(Of String)("towar") And TAB3.Field(Of String)("Dok_przyj") Equals TAB4.Field(Of String)("Dok_przyj")
                Select New With
                         {
                         .TOWAR = TAB3.Field(Of String)("TOWAR"),
                         .STAN = If(IsDBNull(TAB3.Item("STANMAG")), 0, TAB3.Field(Of Double)("STANMAG")),
                         .WAGA = If(IsDBNull(TAB4.Item("WAGA")), 0, TAB4.Field(Of Double)("WAGA"))
                        })

    Dim stock = (From MAG In dane
                 Group MAG By TOWAR = MAG.TOWAR Into G = Group
                 Select New With {
                    .TOWAR = TOWAR,
                    .Stan = G.Where(Function(x) x.STAN > 0).Sum(Function(x) x.STAN),
                    .Waga = G.Where(Function(x) x.STAN > 0).Sum(Function(x) x.WAGA)
                    }
                )
    Dim MAGAZYNGLOWNY = (From tab1 In MAG_GLOW
                         Group Join tab2 In stock On tab2.TOWAR Equals tab1.TOWAR Into co = Group
                         From tab2 In co.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         Order By tab1.TOWAR
                         Select New With
                                     {.TOWAR = tab1.TOWAR,
                                     .NAZWA = tab1.Nazwa,
                                     .Jm = tab1.Jm,
                                     .STAN = If(IsNothing(tab2), Nothing, tab2.Stan),
                                     .WAGA = If(IsNothing(tab2), Nothing, tab2.Waga)
                                     })
```